# Start Spring Boot application using HTTPS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, https

So I went through the following steps:

1. I generated an SSL certificate using the JRE keytool. I executed the
   command:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias tomcat
    -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
    -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650
   ```

   Then I was prompted for a password, and various other information. I
   completed like so:

   ```
   Enter keystore password:
    Re-enter new password:
    What is your first and last name?
    [Unknown]:
    What is the name of your organizational unit?
    [Unknown]:
    What is the name of your organization?
    [Unknown]:
    What is the name of your City or Locality?
    [Unknown]:
    What is the name of your State or Province?
    [Unknown]:
    What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
    [Unknown]:
    Is CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown correct?
    [no]: yes
   ```
2. I then moved the "keystore.p12" file within the `src/main/resources`
   folder of my spring boot application.
3. Added the following lines within the `application.yml` file from
   `src/main/resources`:

   ```
   server:
    port: 8443
    ssl:
     key-store: keystore.p12
     key-store-password: <chosen_password>
     key-store-provider: PKCS12
     key-alias: tomcat
   ```

Started the Spring Boot application. Got this exception:

```
2018-09-18 13:51:25 [main] ERROR o.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase - Failed to load keystore type [JKS] with path [file:/home/user/Desktop/repositories/alfresco-facade-c4/keystore.p12] due to [no such provider: PKCS12]
java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: PKCS12
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:83)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:206)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:698)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:127)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:204)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:184)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:87)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:250)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:193)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at com.docprocess.contentmanagement.AlfrescoFacadeApplication.main(AlfrescoFacadeApplication.java:22)
2018-09-18 13:51:25 [main] ERROR o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:250)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:193)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at com.docprocess.contentmanagement.AlfrescoFacadeApplication.main(AlfrescoFacadeApplication.java:22)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1021)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Failed to load keystore type [JKS] with path [file:/home/user/Desktop/repositories/alfresco-facade-c4/keystore.p12] due to [no such provider: PKCS12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:87)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to load keystore type [JKS] with path [file:/home/user/Desktop/repositories/alfresco-facade-c4/keystore.p12] due to [no such provider: PKCS12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:204)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:184)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

The main idea is that PKCS12 provider does not exist.

Any thoughts ?

Maybe use different provider ? If the answer yes, which provider should I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refactor application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: <chosen_password>
    keyStoreType: PKCS12
    key-alias: tomcat
```

`PKCS12` should work out of the box with spring-boot

Comment: Could you try to build an executable jar and run it from command line?

Comment: Also, try renaming key-store-provider to keyStoreType

Comment: This did the trick. I used `key-store: classpath:keystore.p12` and `keyStoreType: PKCS12`. Please mention this in the answer as well.

Comment: Adjusted answer.